# How to open specific page in application from URL Shared link Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, deep-linking

I need to do two things : First , I want to share Model to social media For example I have product which has title , text, id(or specific url)
I use share.plugin to share this model , Second , I want when user click the link if app is installed it navigate to specific page 
else it navigate to web site page I followed links which talks about deep linking and app indexing but i didn't find something like i want

Note : I Used prism for xamarin forms

Update : I Tried this

```
private void RegisterLink()
        {
            //var url = $"https://unelectronics.com/ar/product/{GenerateSEOTitle(ProductData.ID, ProductData.SKUName)}".Trim();
            var url = "https://unelectronics.com/ar/product/888-lg-55c7v-55-4k-oled-smart-tv";

            var entry = new AppLinkEntry
            {               
                Title = ProductData.Title,
                AppLinkUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                IsLinkActive = true,
            };

            entry.KeyValues.Add("contentType", "product");
            entry.KeyValues.Add("companyName", "UNElectronics");
            entry.KeyValues.Add("appName", "UNElectronics");
            Application.Current.AppLinks.RegisterLink(entry);
        }
```

which is applink concept but it doesn't work for me

Any help ?

Comment: What have you tried (code)?

Comment: I need something like that https://riccardo-moschetti.org/2014/10/03/opening-a-mobile-app-from-a-link-the-xamarin-way-url-schemas/

Comment: @MichaelC. I Update my question